# How do I use two loops at once that function based on button presses? (making a space shuttle for my son!)

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi3

Using python 2.7 my goal is to have an program that runs two loops simultaneously to control LEDs on two separate bargraph LEDs (12 segments). The bargraph LEDs will represent levels of O2 and CO2. The O2 will always be decreasing and the CO2 will always be increasing. Except when you push a button, which causes the levels to go back to 0 for CO2 and 12 for O2. There are two buttons, one for O2 and one for CO2.

Thus far: Using multiprocessing, I can run the loops simultaneously to decrease O2 and increase CO2. When one reaches the limit, a button press returns it to safe levels. For example, when O2 reaches level 0 (i.e all lights off) I can push a button and it enters a loop to fill up. The opposite is true for CO2.

My problem: I can't have the O2 fill up and the CO2 decrease at the same time. When I push the button to increase O2, I have to wait until my CO2 levels are back to zero.. someone's help would be soo appreciated!

Here is a a video of whats going on: 
https://youtu.be/mrxorF0tfCk

Here is my code:

```
from Adafruit_LED_Backpack import BicolorBargraph24
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from sys import exit
import threading


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(0)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

# Create display instance on default I2C address (0x70) and bus number.
display2 = BicolorBargraph24.BicolorBargraph24(address=0x71)
display = BicolorBargraph24.BicolorBargraph24(address=0x70)

# Initialize the display. Must be called once before using the display.
display2.begin()
display.begin()

display.write_display()
display2.write_display()

brightness = 12

g = BicolorBargraph24.GREEN
y = BicolorBargraph24.YELLOW
r = BicolorBargraph24.RED
b = BicolorBargraph24.OFF


led_1 = [r, r, r, r, y, y,
        y, y, y, y, y, y, y, y, y,
        g, g, g, g, g, g,
          g, g, g
           ]
led_2 = [b, b, b, b, b, b,
        b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
        b, b, b, b, b, b,
          b, b, b
           ]
led_1CO2 = [r, r, r, r, r, r,
        r, r, r, r, r, r, y, y, y,
        y, y, y, y, y, g,
          g, g, g
           ]
led_2CO2 = [b, b, b, b, b, b,
        b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
        b, b, b, b, b, b,
          b, b, b
           ]
count = 0



def increaseC02():
        print "increaseC02"
        for index, colour in reversed(list(enumerate(led_1CO2))):
                if index == 0:
                    print "Your CO2 scrubber is almost toast! Replace your cartridge!"
                    os.system('omxplayer alarm1.wav &')
                else:
                    display2.set_bar(index, colour)
                    display2.write_display()
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    print "CO2 : ",index, colour

def useoxygen():
        print "useoxygen"
        for index, colour in reversed(list(enumerate(led_2))):
                if index == 0:
                        print "You've run out of Oxygen! Replace your O2 Cartridge!"
                        os.system('omxplayer alarm1.wav &')
                else:
                        display.set_bar(index, colour)
                        display.write_display()
                        time.sleep(.3)
                        print " O2 : ",index, colour

#########################################################                 
#THIS FUNCTION IS FOR SENSING THE O2 RECHARGE 
def my_callback(channel):
        count = 0
        print ('Oxygen Recharged')
        command1 = "sudo killall -s 9 omxplayer.bin"
        os.system(command1)
        for index, colour in enumerate(led_1):
                if count >= 0 and count < 23:
                        display.set_bar(index, colour)
                        display.write_display()
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        count += 1
                else:
                        useoxygen()


#THIS FUNCTION IS FOR SENSING THE CO2 SCRUBBER REPLACEMENT            
def my_callbackCO2(channel):
        countCO2 = 24
        print ('Carbon Dioxide Scrubber Successfully replaced')
        command1CO2 = "sudo killall -s 9 omxplayer.bin"
        os.system(command1CO2)
        for index, colour in list(enumerate(led_2CO2)):
                if countCO2 > 1:
                        display2.set_bar(index, colour)
                        display2.write_display()
                        time.sleep(.1)
                        countCO2 -= 1
                else:
                        increaseC02()

def always_checking():
        try:
                GPIO.add_event_detect(22, GPIO.FALLING, callback = my_callback, bouncetime=300)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                GPIO.cleanup()
        try:
                GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.FALLING, callback = my_callbackCO2, bouncetime=300)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                GPIO.cleanup()

#########################################################

#START

os.system(' &')

#FILLS UP O2
for index, colour in enumerate(led_1):
        count = 1
        os.system('')
        if count >= 1 and count < 23:
                display.set_bar(index, colour)
                display.write_display()
                time.sleep(.1)
                count += 1
                print "FO2 : ",index, colour, count



#STARTS DECREASING O2 AND INCREASING CO2
p1 = threading.Thread(target=useoxygen)
p2 = threading.Thread(target=increaseC02)
p3 = threading.Thread(target=always_checking)

p3.start()
p2.start()
p1.start()

#p2.join()
#p1.join()
```

Comment: You are using `Threading `, which is very different from multiprocessing in Python. Read about the Python Global Interpreter Lock for more info, but in short : Python does not allow parallel processing, Threading will just pause one Thread to run the other. Threading is only usefull if you have pause in your code (like sleeping times). The solution would be to use multiprocessing, BUT then your processes can't communicate with each other (only through specific objects, like `Pipes` or shared variables, and you are looking at some rewriting of your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, much appreciated. ah yes, sorry, I had bounced back and forth between using multiprocessing and Threading. So my solution is go with multiprocessing and look up how pipes can help me.